# 401 error code when using Soundcloud API OAuth2

Tags: iphone, web-services, http, oauth, soundcloud

I am creating an iPhone app using the TestApp application that came with the Soundcloud
Coca API wrapper download.

When I use the key and client id and call back URL there is no 
problem. I can log into the app using my Soundcloud account and upload 
the my tracks at the touch of a button.

When I switch the client id, key and callback URL to the one that I 
have listed on my developer account the behavior changes. I can log in 
and the app gets registered to my account, but before my username is 
posted to the app I get a **401** at this level in the code:

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection; 
{ 
#if (NXOAuth2ConnectionDebug) 

    NSLog(@"%.0fms (SUCC) - %@", -[startDate 
timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000.0, [self descriptionForRequest:request]); 

#endif 
    printf("connectionDidFinishLoading\n");

        if (sendConnectionDidEndNotification) [[NSNotificationCenter 
defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NXOAuth2DidEndConnection 
object:self]; 

        sendConnectionDidEndNotification = NO; 

    printf("connectDidFinishLoading.1\n"); 
    printf("self.statusCode:   %d \n", self.statusCode);
```

Since my app works perfectly fine with the key, id and callback URL 
given in the TestApp it is strange to me that when I switch these 
values I get the 401.

Just to clarify further:

It is an iOS app and I have definitely placed the correct key and id 
in the correct spot. The client ID and Secret from souncloud.com (not 
sandbox-soundcloud) are plugged into the values directly under

`#ifdef kUseProduction`

This seems to me the correct thing to do. Also, in my info.plist file 
I have the URL identifier

```
com.imc
```

and the URL scheme

```
http://imc
```

which matches exactly the redirect URI have filed with Soundcloud.

Likewise I have defined my kCallbackURL as

```
http://imc
```

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got [the answer from the lovely people at SoundCloud](https://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/f75c225a81554548).